# How do I produce an image of a given number?

Tags: python

I want to rasterize a float (e.g., -1.45) into a numpy array, which I can visualize as a grayscale image. You can think of the result image as a black image with white and gray pixels writing out "-1.45".

I'm surprised there's no off-the-shelf tool to do this. What is the most pythonic way of doing so?

Comment: Have you tried PIL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `matplotlib` to plot the number as text, then convert it to a `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import image

def rasterise_n(n):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1, 1))
    ax.text(0.5, 0.5, n, va='center', ha='center', fontsize=24)
    ax.tick_params(left=False, labelleft=False, bottom=False, labelbottom=False)
    for spine in ax.spines.values():
        spine.set_visible(False)

    fig.canvas.draw()
    return np.frombuffer(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))

result = rasterise_n(1.45)
```